# django redirect to parent of iframe from view

Tags: python, django, iframe

I am having a web page rendered via iframe. On successfully submitting the form in iframe, i gave,

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect("www.google.com")
```

But the target page is also getting loaded within iframe. How to specify the parent to reload from django view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just return some html:

`redirect_template.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.top.location.href = '{{ redirect_url }}';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Instead of:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("www.google.com")
```

Use:

```
return TemplateResponse(request, 'redirect_template.html', {'redirect_url':'www.google.com'}
```

Comment: Do we also need to change the `sandbox` attribute of the parent `<iframe>`?